# Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local Computer... (error code 3417)

Tags: sql-server

For some reasons I moved this folder : (`Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL`) to another drive, then returned it to the same location, but sql server has stopped working, showing this error when trying to start it again:

> Windows could not start the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) on Local
>   Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this
>   is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to
>   service-specific error code 3417.

I tried many solutions discussed in different forums, but none of them work for me.

The folder is not compressed or encrypted.

```
My sql server version is 2012:
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools    11.0.3128.0
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) 6.1.7601.17514
Microsoft MSXML             3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer         9.0.8112.16421
Microsoft .NET Framework            4.0.30319.18047
Operating System                6.1.7601
```

Thanks for your kind help in advance.

Comment: Check that the account running the sql server service has access rights to the folder.

Comment: @jpw, The is fixed :) Thanks a lot for your short and perfect answer :)

Comment: I ran into this problem after changing IPAll to use a specific port.  Couldn't bring the server back online until the setting was changed back to Dynamic Ports.

Comment: how to check it?

Answer (score 92):

Very simple to solve this problem.

Just open **RUN window**(Window+R) and type `services.msc`:

[Services.msc window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6pLK.png)

Find the SQL within name column and right click on that.

right click on SQL as in screenshot

[image]

You will get properties option, click on properties.

One new window will be open and there you have to click on **Log On** tab. And select the **Local System Account.** then apply and okay.

Select Local system Account

[image]

After that come again in `services.msc` window. and **right click** on sql and **click start**.

And finally, SQL Server services started successfully. enjoy and keep learning.

Comment: THANKSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS

Comment: I am getting `Error 1053`, any idea?

Comment: Everything was working fine, for years, and then one day boom. This answer saved the day, thanks!!!

Comment: didn't work for me

Comment: If lossed rights to connect to database server instance I know that you will not be able to connect to workstation nor change configuration values but is there a way to do either or?

Comment: the same with @ShaiwalTripathi, but I restarted my machine after applying all the changes, then it worked :)

Comment: Worked for me in 2008 R2. Legend.

Answer (score 28):

Run this command after opening cmd as administrator

```
net start mssqlserver /T902
```

This command is called trace flag 902. It is used to bypass script upgrade mode. Every time when you try to start your sql service it also looks for script upgrades. and when the script upgrade fail your service unable to start. So, Whenever we have such upgrade script failure issue and SQL is not getting started, we need to use trace flag 902 to start SQL.

I hope this will help you..

Answer (score 17):

Check if you did compress the driver or folder in where you put the .mdf file.

If so, plesae goto the driver or folder, change the compress option by

> Properties -> Advanced and unticked the “Compress contents to save disk space” checkbox.

After above things, you should be able to start the service again.

Comment: This could be my issue. Where is the .mdf file located by default?

Comment: Yes, I once mistakenly compressed the C drive, but later cancelled the process. Yet some of the files/folder remained compressed. SQL Server installation folders were compressed... Uncompressing the whole Program Files folder again, did the trick. The error 3417 gone! :-)

Answer (score 11):

In my particular case, I fixed this error by looking in the Event Viewer to get a clue as to the source of the issue:

[image]

I then followed the steps outlined at [Rebuilding Master Database in SQL Server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmW81.png).

> Note: Take some good backups first. After erasing the master database, you will have to attach to all of your existing databases again by browsing to the `.mdf files`.

In my particular case, the command to rebuild the master database was:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Setup Bootstrap\SQLServer2012>setup /ACTION=rebuilddatabase /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=mike /sapwd=[insert password]
```

Note that this will reset SQL server to its defaults, so you will have to hope that you can restore the master database from `E:\backup\master.bak`. I couldn't find this file, so attached the existing databases (by browsing to the existing `.mdf` files), and everything was back to normal.

After fixing everything, [I created a maintenance plan to back up everything, including the master database, on a weekly basis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms191002.aspx).

In my particular case, this whole issue was caused by a Seagate hard drive getting bad sectors a couple of months after its 2-year warranty period expired. Most of the Seagate drives I have ever owned have ended up expiring either before or shortly after warranty - so I'm avoiding Seagate like the plague now!!

Answer (score 5):

This usually occurs when the master.mdf or the mastlog.ldf gets corrupt. In order to solve the issue go to the following path `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL` , there you will find a folder ” Template Data ” , copy the master.mdf and mastlog.ldf and replace it in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Data folder` . That's it. Now start the MS SQL service and you are done.

Comment: I searched for `mastlog.ldf` in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` and found `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn\Templates`. I replaced the file as per these instructions but it did not seem to fix the problem in my particular case.

Comment: this way is work for me. Copy backup master data to Data folder. and start services SQL Server again.

Comment: after "recreating" the master db (e.g. as described here) - you'll need to reattach your database - Sql Server Mng --> Databases --> Attach

Answer (score 5):

I have had the same error recently. I have checked the folder Log of my Server instance.

```
x:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\
```

and I have found this errors in logs

```
Starting up database 'master'.
Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1.
FCB::Open failed: Could not open file
x:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf for file number 1.  OS error: 5(Access is denied.).
Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.
Unable to open the physical file "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\master.mdf". Operating system error 5:    "5(Access is denied.)".
Error: 17204, Severity: 16, State: 1. FCB::Open failed: Could not open file E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf for file number 2.  OS  error: 5(Access is denied.).
Error: 5120, Severity: 16, State: 101.  Unable to open the physical file "E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\mastlog.ldf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
SQL Server shutdown has been initiated
```

So for me it was an easy fix. I just added proper access rights to this files to the sql server service account.
I hope it will help

Answer (score 4):

What is System Event Log saying?

Have you tried to repair:
Sql Server Installation Center -> Maintenance -> Repair

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, using `Repair` didn't fix the issue in my particular case.

Answer (score 4):

In My case I had to **Upgrade** the SQL Server since evaluation licence had been expired.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this error today. And above answers didn't help me. I was getting this error when I try to start the SQL Server(SQLEXPRESS) service in Services(services.msc).

When I checked the error log at the location C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Log, there was an entry related TCP/IP port.

> 2018-06-19 20:41:52.20 spid12s     TDSSNIClient initialization failed
>   with error 0x271d, status code 0xa. Reason: Unable to initialize the
>   TCP/IP listener. An attempt was made to access a socket in a way
>   forbidden by its access permissions.

Recently I was running a MSSQLEXPRESS image in my docker container, which was using the same TCP/IP port, that caused this issue.

[image]

So, what I did is, I just reset my TCP/IP by doing the below command.

`netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt`

[image]

Once the resetting is done, I had to restart the machine and when I try to start the SQLEXPRESS service again, it started successfully. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the services and check if the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is running. Stop it and start your SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) service. It should work.

see the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure both drive have the same partition - ( like  FAT or  NTFS, preferably NTFS ) also make sure he NETWORK SERVICE account, has the access.

Answer (score 0):

Database rebuild fixed it for me as well. Also had to restore the old database from backup as it got corrupted during power outage...
The copy master.mdf procedure did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem before

the error code 3417 : the SQL SERVER cannot start the master database, 
without master db SQL SERVER can't start 
[MSSQLSERVER_3417](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337262(v=sql.100).aspx)

> The master database records all the system-level information for a SQL Server system. This includes instance-wide metadata such as logon accounts, endpoints, linked servers, and system configuration settings. In SQL Server, system objects are no longer stored in the master database; instead, they are stored in the Resource database. Also, master is the database that records the existence of all other databases and the location of those database files and records the initialization information for SQL Server. Therefore, SQL Server cannot start if the master database is unavailable
>   [MSDN Master DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187837.aspx/)
>   ***so you need to reconfigure all settings after restoring master db***

**solutions**

- replace master mdf and ldf files with the same files from another instance of sql Server as long as its the same version [reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/fort_sql/archive/2011/02/01/the-easiest-way-to-rebuild-the-sql-server-master-database.aspx)
- Rebuild System Databases [refrence](http://www.mytechmantra.com/LearnSQLServer/Rebuild_System_Databases_In_SQL_Server_2008.html)
- reinstall sql server

Answer (score 0):

I copied a master.mdf und mastlog.ldf from another Computer (luckily, we have a lot of Clients with the same configuration, otherwise template data would be perhaps necessary). I backed up the damaged master.mdf and mastlog.mdf. After that I replaced the bad ones with the ones from another Computer. And it worked. I needed to start the MSSQLSERVER Service of course. But, after that I had Problem that the user was already existing but orphaned (error code 15023), I executed the query

USE Database_name
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'Auto_Fix', 'username'

after that, everything was working smoothly. Hope this helps you and many thanks for this thread, saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the current ErrorLog to any other name like Errorlog _Old and change any old Log file to Error log file

try to start the SQL server services.. That's it. it will work..

Sql server error log file got corrupted. that is why it gives the problem even when you have all permissions.. when you delete it. new file will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue after changing database location. And I solved it by moving system databases back to their default locations. Although I will recommend not to move system databases like master and model to some other location. But if you want then you can refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/move-system-databases?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

Re-entering credentials will help to start the services:

1. Start > Services
2. Right click on SQL Sever > Properties
3. Log On
4. Re-enter credentials and apply
5. Start the services now

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind getting this **Error Code : 3417** may be as follows:

- One cause may be due to the Network account for the Data folder in
  Program files.
- The other reason may be because of some Windows
  settings changed somehow.

**Example**: If for some reasons you have moved this folder (Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL) to another location then returned it to the same location. So, though it was returned to the same location the server may stop working and show error code 3417 when trying to start it again.

***How To Fix SQL Error 3417***

- Go to "C:Program Files Microsoft SQLServerMSSQL.1MSSqLData"
- Security/Permission settings
- Network Service Account
- Add a Network Service account
- Then again check all

As stated [here](https://www.scarydba.com/2020/09/23/review-stellar-repair-for-sql-server/), you can try this third party tool as well.

Answer (score 0):

A few times now, I've experienced various instances MS SQL Server to fail with this error after a Windows update. Most of the quick fixes above did not work for me.

What did:

- copy all production databases over to some safe place
- remove everything SQL Server via add/remove programs
- get the latest SQL Server Express or Dev & install it
- move the databases over to their home and reattach them.

For me, this was the fastest solution. Trying to find the cause of the error and fixing it is an afternoon of googling misty error messages. But YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was about evaluation period expiration. I also went through this thread of StackOverFlow.You can investigate your problem by going to `Event Viewer --> Windows Log (Application)` and then search for your error id. For Step by Step guide to view error id in event viewer visit [this...](https://sqlwithmanoj.com/2015/05/31/windows-could-not-start-the-sql-server-refer-to-service-specific-error-code-17051-sql-server-evaluation-period-has-expired/)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, and after more than 3 hours of searching and trying several solutions I solved my problem using this method:

- Run SQL Configuration Manager
- Double click on SQL Server Network Configuration
- Protocols for "**Yous Server Instance Name**"
- On the right pane, Right click the TCP/IP and click Properties
- Go to the last option "**Listener All**" and changed to "**No**"

Then, the server restarted to apply changes, and the problem solved.

This method from this solution https://serverfault.com/a/443384/1061098

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the drive letter had changed.
Putting the drive letter back to D resolved the issue.