# SQL Server 'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 226

Tags: sql-server

When I connect to **SQL Server**, I get an error 3417, and I can not restart the SQL Server Instance, then I look for the Event Viewer, and find the error message:

> Script level upgrade for database 'master' failed because upgrade step
>   'msdb110_upgrade.sql' encountered error 226, state 6, severity 16.
>
> This is a serious error condition which might interfere with regular
>   operation and the database will be taken offline. If the error
>   happened during upgrade of the 'master' database, it will prevent the
>   entire SQL Server instance from starting. Examine the previous
>   errorlog entries for errors, take the appropriate corrective actions
>   and re-start the database so that the script upgrade steps run to
>   completion.

Comment: what did you do prior to `When I connect to the SQL Server, I get the error 3417`

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273021/windows-could-not-start-the-sql-server-mssqlserver-on-local-computer-error

Comment: I do nothing, I can not access the SQL Server suddenly .