# Not able to connect to SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

One day it was working, the next its not.
When I try to log into sql I get this error

[image: Error on SQL]
I've tried solutions both on this site as well as youtube tutorials and neither are working.

Here's the error I get when trying to get SQL to run through the config.

[image: Error in config settings]

And here's the error when trying to get SQL to run through services.msc

[image]

Comment: Did you review the logs? Any error?

Comment: The error logs just say the same thing as the error windows that pop up when trying to run

Comment: please have a look in this issue.you might find your answer [windows could not start SQLServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273021/windows-could-not-start-the-sql-server-mssqlserver-on-local-computer-error)

Comment: @J_Shrestha I've tried everything that link suggests and it still doesn't work

Comment: Please update your question with **SQL Server error log**. Paste the whole log, it's short. It may be that the port is already occupied or any other reason, but SQL Server wrote it in it's log

Comment: Is the service running under a specific user account? What does the log on tab tell us? If so, then it maybe a login/password related issue. Also it could be a local security policy thing. If not, then look in the file called ERRORLOG. Default located somewhere like this: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14\MSSQL\Log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a custom database in the file I was using.
I deleted it and remade it, and everything works normally now

Answer (score 2):

The last screenshot shows the error code: 17051.

It means:

> **17051** – SQL Server Evaluation period has expired

Therefore to make it working again [Upgrade](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms143393%28v%3Dsql.110%29) the license to paid versions like "Standard" or "Enterprise" or  to a free edition - "Developer"

This can be done via SQL Server Installation Center:

[image]